# customized sorting using search term in django

Tags: django, sorting, django-rest-framework

I am searching a term "john" in a list of dict ,

I have a list of dict like this :

```
"response": [
    {
        "name": "Alex T John"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ajo John"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",

    }]
```

I am using :

```
response_query = sorted(response, key = lambda i: i['name'])
```

response_query return ascending order of result only but I need a result with first name as a priority.

Expected result:

```
    {
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "name": "Ajo John"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alex T John",

    }
```

The  first name containing search term  should appear first.

Comment: Would using `sorted(response, key = lambda i: i['name'].index('John'))` do it?

Comment: How do you know which part of name stands for the first name? Or all you're asking about is `sorted(..., reverse=True)`?

Comment: @Shinratensei But its showing result like John Cap , John Dio , John.But it should be like  John,John Cap , John Dio

Comment: `sorted(response, key = lambda i: i['name'].index('John') + len(i['name']))`, but I feel like you have many conditions and this lambda might end up being unreadable and you should implement a method that does a slower but more accurate sorting

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort with priorities you can try a key-function that returns tuple. In your particular case,  as far as I got the question, this function will work fine:

```
response_query = sorted(
    response,
    key=lambda i: (len(i['name'].split()) > 1, i['name'])
)
```

In other words, I added the condition `len(i['name'].split()) > 1` that return `False` (it will go first) if the `name` consists of one word only, else `True`.

For the case, if you need the priority condition as the `name` starts with the term you used in the search, the result would be:

```
term = 'john'
...
response_query = sorted(
    response,
    key=lambda i: (not i['name'].lower().startswith(term), i['name'])
)
```

Comment: So, please, clarify in your question what you mean in first priority. The name that consists of one word or name that starts with the word you are looking for, or anything else. I find your question is not clear enough to be answered.

Comment: name that consists of one word

Comment: So what I suggested works fine. It also returns the result you need.

Comment: By using your code the term contains last name appearing first.

Comment: my result :   John , Abraham T John , John C

Comment: Because `John C` consists of two words and goes after `Abraham T John` in alphabetic order.

Comment: @JishaTechversant I updated my answer. Maybe that is what you are looking for.